# How to disable gradle minify for html files in raw directory

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

when using

> minifyEnabled true

in my build.gradle file, html files are somehow obfuscated and can no more be accessed by WebView , files are not found because the files names changed i guess.

Any way to get around this behavour ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines to proguard:

`-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {public static <fields>;}
-keep class **.R$*`

**Update**

If there are specific resources you wish to keep or discard, create an XML file in your project with a `<resources>` tag and specify each resource to keep in the `tools:keep` attribute and each resource to discard in the `tools:discard` attribute. Both attributes accept a comma-separated list of resource names. You can use the asterisk character as a wild card.

For example:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:keep="@layout/l_used*_c,@layout/l_used_a,@layout/l_used_b*"
    tools:discard="@layout/unused2" />`

Save this file in your project resources, for example, at res/raw/keep.xml. The build does not package this file into your APK.

Specifying which resources to discard might seem silly when you could instead delete them, but this can be useful when using build variants. For example, you might put all your resources into the common project directory, then create a different keep.xml file for each build variant when you know that a given resource appears to be used in code (and therefore not removed by the shrinker) but you know it actually won't be used for the given build variant.

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html

Comment: this will keep all resources ?

Comment: i have an html file in raw folder (file for about app) that i want to keep from obfuscation not a specific resource or layout, the html file have to be packed with the apk but not obfuscated

Comment: I'm looking for all information about the problem and I stumbled upon this blog, http://techan0.blogspot.com.eg/2015/08/proguard-observations.html?m=1 it's not a solution but clraified the issue to me

Comment: if i understood well, there is no way to get proguard work simply saying him "hey, leave that single file alone" !

Comment: so should i hard-code it in some java file or integrate it with string values and load html text ?

Comment: I think strings would be better